# problems with jQuery Mobile and-webkit-transform: scale in mobile devices

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile, responsive-design

When I add my web jquery mobile elements associated with `-webkit-transform: scale (x, x)` lose their properties

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Galaxy Camara</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Test">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <img id="test" src="css/img/marketIcon.png" style="-webkit-transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);">
        <img id="test2" src="css/img/marketIcon.png">
    </header>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show your code so we can see where the bug is.

Comment: They do? http://jsfiddle.net/ZmLKg/